# How to fix ORA-00937: not a single-group group function in my query in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT id,
       managerID,
       MAX(salary)
  FROM DataTable
 WHERE id >
          ( SELECT id
              FROM DataTable
             WHERE salary <= 10
               AND managerID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          )
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of this query?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation would all help.  The query makes no sense at all.  The missing group by is only one of multiple errors.

Comment: Simply put, you cannot aggregate without a ```GROUP BY```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Your query is throwing an error because you cannot use `having` without using `group by`.
> 2. You are missing `group by` in outer query as well, whenever you use aggregate function you have to use `group by`
> 3. you have to give an alias to your sub-query

Replace your query with following.

```
select 
  id,
  manager_id, 
  max(salary) 
from DataTable 
where id > (
  select 
    id 
  from DataTable 
  where salary <=10
  group by
    id
  having count(*)>1
) t
group by
   id,
   manager_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just run your query but now error is ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

Comment: @kodder360 you cannot have just `AND managerId`, you have to assign some value to it.

Comment: @kodder360 did you try?